# Initializing an empty array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am writing a program in C++ and I need to initialize an array of a struct object I have created. It looks something like this:

```
typedef struct {
float x;
float y;
} vec2;
```

And then I initialize an array like this:

```
vec2 hotSpot[1000];
```

I thought when I initialized such an array, it would be completely empty, but when I print the value of sizeof(hotSpot), it says 8000!

Am I going wrong somewhere, or have I misunderstood some concept? How do I make this array empty?

Comment: Don't typedef your structs. Wherever you got that idea from, abandon it right now, since it is not C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `hotSpot` can not be empty as you initialized it as an array of 1000. There for, there are 1000 elements.

When `vec2 hotSpot[1000];` happens, it places all 1000 values as an [uninitialized variable.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable)

The elements in `hotSpot` are not valid as they have not been initialized. If you are looking to set them all to zero, you could use [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/) to initialize them all to zero.

For more information on arrays, please take a look at [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/).

Comment: I'm not sure why you deleted your old answer rather than editing it, but I'll repost my comment -- value-initialization would be far preferable to `memset` (which has no real place in modern C++ code).

Comment: memset is still a very common and valid practice though to quickly set a large set a values.

Comment: It's a common practice in _C_, where it's necessary; it is not (or _should_ not be) common in C++. Value-initialization has well-defined behavior, is more idiomatic, and is less typing.

Comment: @ildjarn why should memset not be used in c++? I just used it and it seems to suit my requirements. 

as a follow up to is there a way I can now access the first available null, or zerofied, element of the array?

Comment: @CanIHaveSomeChange : `memset` shouldn't be used because it is 100% redundant in C++. For any type where `memset` is safe, value-initialization will accomplish the same thing more efficiently.

Comment: @ildjarn what's the difference between memset and value-initialization? Both will iterate through the array to initialize the values? And that makes both take n time. How is one faster than the other? Can you give an example of value initialization?

Comment: @ildjarn: your comments are misleading. C++ defines trivially copyable and trivially constructible types for a reason. There are places where you explicitly want to efficiently deal with bytes without interference of any fancy C++ abstractions. Implementation of something like an `std::string`, blitting images, numeric computations etc. are examples thereof.

Comment: @ybungalobill : I agree with all of that. But, value-initialization is always strictly better than `memset(0)`, period.

Comment: @ildjarn: this is contradictory. You also give no explanation of how value initialization is "better". It is as efficient as `memset` on large objects if your compiler is smart enough to convert it to a `memset` call, otherwise you'll end up with a terribly slow loop. On compile-time small objects `memset` will be expanded on any compiler where it is an intrinsic to be as efficient as value-initialization. There're no arguments for exclusive use of value-initialization except that it's 'more idiomatic C++'. But it doesn't apply for low-level cases I mentioned. abort(). semicolon.

Comment: @ybungalobill : Using `memset` instead of initialization wouldn't pass code review anywhere I've ever worked, and that has certainly involved plenty of "low-level" code. I'm not selling anything (i.e. I've no investment here). You sound as convinced as I, so there's certainly no point in arguing here of all places.

Answer (score 6):

Your array is not, and can never be "empty". It has, and will always have, 1000 elements. Thus is the nature of C++ arrays.

The problem is that those elements are not in any deterministic state, and indeed accessing any element that has not been initialized is *undefined behaviour*.

More generally, objects in C++ can never be "empty". They always exist. If an object didn't exist, there wouldn't be an object. Some objects always exist in a definite state, while other objects (such as primitive types, or a named object after having been `std::move`d) can exist in an uninitialized or indeterminate state -- they still exist, but the only thing you're allowed to do with them is *assign* a value to them.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want to initialize your 'empty' array this way:

```
vec2 hotSpot[]; // Defines an array of undefined length
```

But if you want to initialize it as 'empty', i.e. fill its entire content with zeros:

```
vec2 hotSpot[1000]; // Defines an array of 1000 items in length
memset(hotSpot, 0, sizeof(hotSpot)); // Fill the array with zeros
```

Comment: Ughhh.. more `memset` recommendations. :-[ This is not C, it's C++; use _language_ facilities to initialize things, not libraries.

Comment: The thing is, I want this array to be empty when I create it. That means, it should be NULL. So when I say sizeof(hotSpot), it must print '0'. Is this possible?

Comment: And if I use "vec2 hotSpot[];", It gives me an error saying "size of hotSpot unknown".

Answer (score 0):

they are empty data-wise, but memory allocated to be able to hold 1000 * 2 float * 4 bytes

Comment: What does `1000 * 2 float * 4 bytes` mean? Where are your 4 magic bytes coming from? (Note that `sizeof(float)` == 4.)

Comment: vec2 hotSpot[1000]; there are 1000 vec2. in each vec2 there are 2 floats. each float has 4 bytes. does that sound magical? not to me.

Comment: Not when you word it that way, but your answer doesn't word it that way. ;-]

Answer (score 0):

A float is just 4 bytes in your machine.When initialized,the hotSpot takes up 8000 totally.